# wampserveur 3 how to access from my smartphone?

Tags: wamp

I can't find the line in httpd.conf to write "Allow from all" to access wamp from my iPhone.

I try to write "Allow from all" about everywhere but nothing work, I need help because I can't find anything concerning wampserver3 and I'm loosing time so much.

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0):

The solution on wampserver3 is effectively different, you have to add "Require ip 192.168.0.0/24" on line 285 of httpd.conf, just under Require local:

```
284: #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
285:     Require local
286:     Require ip 192.168.0.0/24
287: </Directory>
```